# Change image source inner modal on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, image, modal-dialog, on-the-fly

I am trying to change the source image of an image HTML element `<img src="/some/dynamic/path"></img>`.

How I take the `this.id` is very complex and is outside the context of this question, but suffice to know that it is obtained by PHP and at the time of click, on a list item (not showed here), the identifier is already set and ready for use. The `console.log` ensures that.

The problem is that when I click on the element, the modal appears to me, but I do not see the image. By debugging on the browser I noticed that the `src` field is always empty.

I suppose the cause of the problem is to be found in the Javascript code I posted. In particular, the execution of the two instructions is somewhat asynchronous.

What do you think about it? Do you need further details?

---

> The modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body text-center">
                <img id="modalImage" src="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> And the JS code:

```
$(".listShowCard").click(function() {
    console.log("/images/cards/"+this.id+".png");
    $("#modalImage").src="/images/cards/"+this.id+".png";
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
document.getElementById('modalImage').src=`/images/cards/${this.id}.png`;
```

When you're using elements with IDs, try to avoid jQuery, since the call is so much slower than pure JS call.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#modalImage").attr('src', "/images/cards/" + this.id + ".png")
```